# Filling a 2D accelerate array one row at a time

Tags: haskell, accelerate-haskell

```
λ> import Data.Array.Accelerate
λ> import Data.Array.Accelerate.Interpreter (run)
```

Say you have a a 2D accelerate array:

```
λ> :t arr
arr :: Acc (Array DIM2 Int)
λ> run $ unit $ shape arr
Scalar Z [Z :. 4 :. 3]
```

and a 1D accelerate vector of length 4 (the same as the number of colums of `arr`):

```
λ> :t vec
vec :: Acc (Array DIM1 Int)
λ> run $ unit $ shape vec
Scalar Z [Z :. 4]
```

and a function from a scalar to a vector of length 3:

```
expand :: Exp Int -> Acc (Array DIM1 Int)
```

How can you populate `arr` by mapping `expand` on `vec`?

The regular `map` from `Prelude` does not work on accelerate arrays. The `map` from `Data.Array.Accelerate` only maps from element to element.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `expand` returns a vector of the same length on different argument, right? So, mapping such a function over a vector would create a jagged array, which I believe, accelerate does not support. For that reason you can't map a function over an array that produces another array for each element.

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich There is no type-level guarantee. The library usually has a way of dealing with this problem --- `zip`s, as the simplest example are only the extent of the smallest input array. Similar solutions exist for `permute`s and `stencil`s. In the situation explained in the post, a sensible approach would be specify to fill the target array using a specified value if the vector from `expand` is too short, or to drop values if it's too long. Filling a `N`-dimensional array by `N-1` dimensional arrays at a time seems like a necessary use case.

Comment: There is a big difference from the functions you have mentioned. You know the size of the source arrays that are passed to `zip`, `permute`, `stencil`, so you can compute the size of the result array, hence you can allocate it. With a function you want, the end size of the array would depend on the content of the source array (the one you are mapping over), so you can't calculate how much memory you need to allocate ahead of time. You could potentially create a partial function that would expect a set size and throw an error if contract is broken, but that's not nice :)

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich In the example, that problem is explicitly dealt with by populating a pre-allocated array (`arr`) of known shape. It could also be dealt with by specifying the shape (and, as said, a default value or matrix) upfront. I really don't see any problem there. You could even make it simpler by throwing an error if the vector from `expand` is too short, and dropping values if its too long. That's what `fromList` does if the source list is too long or short compared to the specified array shape.

Comment: You can't "populating a pre-allocated array" with accelerate, there is no mutable interface, so you can't change it's values once it has been created.

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich You can, using `permute`. The problem outlined in the original post is even solvable using `permute`, if `expand` returns a prelude list (still of a length unknown to the type-system) instead of a vector.